# Cannot convert a wide character string to a multibyte character string

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to convert a wide character string to a multi-byte character string.

The following program gives me an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main( void )
{
    size_t   i;
    char      *pMBBuffer = (char *)malloc( BUFFER_SIZE );
    wchar_t*pWCBuffer = L"Hello, world.";

    printf( "Convert wide-character string:\n" );

    // Conversion
    wcstombs_s(&i, pMBBuffer, (size_t)BUFFER_SIZE,
               pWCBuffer, (size_t)BUFFER_SIZE );

    // Output
    printf("   Characters converted: %u\n", i);
    printf("    Multibyte character: %s\n\n",
     pMBBuffer );

    // Free multibyte character buffer
    if (pMBBuffer)
    {
    free(pMBBuffer);
    }
}
```

I compiled with a C++11 compiler. The error is:

```
error: ‘wcstombs_s’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘wcstombs’?
   19 |     wcstombs_s(&i, pMBBuffer, (size_t)BUFFER_SIZE,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  `wcstombs_s` is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: Now the real question is: Why do you want to trash your data? Converting (presumably) UTF-16 encoded text to any other encoding (that isn't UTF-8) is a lossy operation.

Comment: use WideCharToMultiByte function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte

Comment: @DrewDormann I use g++ -std=c++11  test_wchar_t.c

Comment: @SimonMourier I work under Ubuntu, does this function exist ?

Comment: You marked the question with [winapi] tag, WideCharToMultiByte is a Windows API, so it can work if you have a way to bind to a Windows API (if you have minGW for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101384/403671 where MessageBox is a Windows API). Of course the program would not be portable on other platform.

Comment: I changer the function wcstombs_s with wcstombs  as following :

Comment: it works fine by changing wcstombs_s to wcstombs which receives as parameters the pointers to the char array and the wchar_t array and the size of the char array.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the funcion wcstombs_s to wcstombs as following :
It works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main( void )
{
    size_t   i;
    char      *pMBBuffer = (char *)malloc( BUFFER_SIZE );
    wchar_t*pWCBuffer = L"Hello, world.";

    printf( "Convert wide-character string:\n" );

        wcstombs(pMBBuffer, pWCBuffer, (size_t)BUFFER_SIZE);



    // Output
    printf("    Multibyte character: %s\n\n",
     pMBBuffer );

    // Free multibyte character buffer
    if (pMBBuffer)
    {
    free(pMBBuffer);
    }
}
~
```

~