# use c++ iostream cin multiple times after command line less than sign reaches eof

Tags: c++, command-line, cin, eof

I am testing this customized code from C++ Primer 5th edition to read a sorted list of words using the **less than sign** from the windows command line while running the program and then ask the user to input a word to be searched for in the list; but the problem is that if I use the "less than sign" in the command prompt the code ignores further cin input requests however by entering a list of words manually and using ctrl+z (^Z) to terminate the cin input with an EOF and then ingoring that input and clearing the cin flags to goodbit (std::cin.clear();) the code recognizes the following cin input request.
So what should be done to achieve the same result when using the **less than < sign** in command line to automate word list creation?

here is the example code:

so compile it and run it like this: `a.exe < word_list.txt`

and it fails to use "std::cin >> sought;" properly.

I have also commented out some tests for std::cin.rdstate() to show that the cin state is the same before and after receiving the eof by ignoring and clearing cin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> text;
    std::string word;
    //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
    while (std::cin >> word)
        text.push_back(word);
    std::cout << "Enter a word to search:" << std::endl;
    std::string sought;
    //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore(1, std::cin.eof());
    std::cin.clear();
    //std::cout << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;

    std::cin >> sought;
    // text must be sorted
    // beg and end will denote the range we're searching
    auto beg = text.begin(), end = text.end();
    auto mid = text.begin() + (end - beg)/2; // original midpoint
    // while there are still elements to look at and we haven't yet found sought
    while (mid != end && *mid != sought) {
        if (sought < *mid) // is the element we want in the first half?
            end = mid; // if so, adjust the range to ignore the second half
        else // the element we want is in the second half
            beg = mid + 1; // start looking with the element just after mid
        mid = beg + (end - beg)/2; // new midpoint, we do not have operator+ for iterators
    }
    if (*mid == sought)
        std::cout << "the result (" << sought << ") was found";
    else
        std::cout << sought << " was not found";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You asked the command shell to run your program with the standard input pointing to a file. It won't magically repoint itself to the interactive console once the file is consumed, as you appear to expect. You can clear the flags, but next time you read, it'll try to read from that same file again, and encounter the same EOF.

Comment: Then isn't there a way to stop the program referencing the same file for the stream input once you point it through the command shell? Isn't there any buffer or whatever to be cleared?

Comment: Not in standard C++, no. There may be [operating system-specific mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020790/using-stdin-with-an-allocconsole) (this one is for Windows).